# Chart.js, changing the max height (not w/ canvas) or rounding up rule?

Tags: javascript, charts, rounding, chart.js

I am trying to get a chart working with the Chart.js library. 
My max value is 16 for this chart. However the default chart seems to go to 20 **or** is just rounding up to 20 from 16. Is there a way I can make 16 the max height of the chart (not the size of the canvas). I've read lots of the great documentation on chart.js I just can't seem to find a rule that targets the max height specifically! Thanks!

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bencasalino/fskahepz/)

```
datasets: [
           {
             label: "test",
             fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
             strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
             pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
             pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
             pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
             pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
             data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
           },  etc.....
```

when I set the max value of the data as 4, the highest point on the chart is 4. However when I set it to 16 the highest point on the chart is now 20. Any ideas on how to set the default rounding value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just override the scale instead, like so

```
     ...
     scaleOverride: true,
     scaleSteps: 15,
     scaleStepWidth: 1,
     scaleStartValue: 1,
 });
```

for a value range from 1 to 16.

Comment: No worries! You might want to delete your other question though - seems pretty much the same as this one. cheers!